# Vue2 video player; How to import flash plugin?

Tags: html, flash, ecmascript-6, vue.js, video.js

I am creating a web player that support both html5 and flash. I am using vue-video-player and wrapping in in a component.
I have installed both videojs-flash and videojs-flvjs.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueVideoPlayer from 'vue-video-player'
// import VideoJsFlash from 'videojs-flash'
// import VideoJsFlash from 'videojs-flvjs'

require('video.js/dist/video-js.css')
require('vue-video-player/src/custom-theme.css')

// const { videojs } = VueVideoPlayer
// videojs.plugin('flashPlugin', VideoJsFlash)
// videojs.addLanguage('ml', myLanguageObject)
// videojs.registerPlugin('flashPlugin', VideoJsFlash)

Vue.use(VueVideoPlayer)
```

Then my playerOptions are

```
playerOptions: {
    // videojs options
    muted: true,
    language: 'en',
    techOrder: ['html5', 'flvjs'], // or ['html5', 'flash']
    playbackRates: [0.7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
    width: '800px',
    height: '800px',
    plugins: {

    },
    flash: {
      swf: './#/assets/video-js.swf'
    },
    poster: './#/assets/logo.png',
    sources: [
    ]
}
```

I hope to play the video

The error I get is as follows,

> video.cjs.js?0e26:441 VIDEOJS: ERROR: The "flvjs" tech is undefined. Skipped browser support check for that tech.
>
> PlayVid.vue?139b:134 the player is readied Player {player_: Player, options_: {…}, id_: "vjs_video_506", name_: null, eventBusEl_: div#vjs_video_506.video-js.vjs-paused.vjs_video_506-dimensions.vjs-controls-enabled.vjs-workinghover…, …}
>
> video.cjs.js?0e26:441 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. MediaError {code: 4, message: "The media could not be loaded, either because the …rk failed or because the format is not supported."}

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueVideoPlayer from 'vue-video-player'
import 'vue-video-player/src/custom-theme.css'
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css'
import 'videojs-flash'
Vue.use(VueVideoPlayer)
```

and playerOptions

```
playerOptions: {
    // videojs options
    muted: true,
    language: 'en',
    techOrder: ['html5', 'flash'],
    playbackRates: [0.7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
    width: '800px',
    height: '800px',
    poster: './#/assets/logo.png',
    sources: [{
      type: "video/x-flv",
      src: "https:/
    }]
}
```